# What is the latest development on database access? ORM?

Tags: dart

I have created a form that allows input from users. That data is sent to serverside dart code. I would like to store the data in a database.

What is the latest development on database access? ORM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our team is using [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) database and the [Dart Mongo drivers](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/mongo_dart) for a production application with active users.

We are also using the [Objectory ORM](https://github.com/vadimtsushko/objectory/) that you might want to use. It makes the use of the database simpler.

As an example, you can define a model:

```dart
class Person extends PersistentObject {
  get name => getProperty('name');
  set name(value) => setProperty('name', value);
}
```

Then creating a new instance and saving it to the database goes like this:

```dart
var p = new Person()
  ..name = 'Jack Bauer';

p.save();
```

We've been happy with Mongo and I'm pretty sure it will serve you well too.

Comment: Is there any documentation, examples or articles on how to use the dart mongo drivers? Except for the github material.

Comment: Check out the examples folder or the unit tests. They have various code samples. You can also always ask here for specific Dart Mongo questions :)

Comment: Mongo_dart looks awesome!